# How to group / resample a column based on strings rather than timeformat as known from pandas resample

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I would like to ask for a little support. I used google place API in order to get the formatted addresses of some suppliers.

My target is to check the addresses from the raw data and to compare with the ones proposed by Google.

So I managed to create a frame out of the data provided by Google with columns (Name, street_Google, ZIP_Google, Country_Google)

My raw file has also a similar structure (Name, street_raw)

In order to check if the addresses are similar I execute a fuzzy comparison, in which I compare the streets with each other and put the data into a column. The image below shows my output excel file with **Street_X** as the raw street, **Street_Y** the google provided data and **Similarity** as the fuzzy result

Here is the step I cannot go further and would be happy for any kind of support.

How can I group the supplier and keep the maximum of each supplier group, so that the frame has exactly the same column title as the screenshot and the following entries

The result should for example be: keept row[0],row[2],[3],row[4] to the corresponding columns
[image]

I tried with the groupby function, however it creates multiple indices

Please find below my code

```
from pprint import pprint
from thefuzz import fuzz
import pandas as pd
import requests
import googlemaps
from urllib.parse import urlencode
API_KEY="API"
map_client=googlemaps.Client(API_KEY)


vendor_data_pl=pd.read_excel(path)


supplier_name=vendor_data_pl["Supplier name"][:10]
#supplier_name=["HELLMANN WORLDWIDE LOGISTICS POLSKA SP. Z O.O. SP. K.","SIEMENS SP. Z O.O."]
supplier_list=[]
address_list=[]
phone_list=[]

for name in supplier_name:
    response=map_client.places(query=name)
    results=response.get("results")
    MultipleLocation=len(results)
    if MultipleLocation>= 1:
        for i in range (MultipleLocation):
            PlaceID=results[i]["place_id"]
            url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json"
            params={
                "key":API_KEY,
                "place_id":PlaceID,
                "inputtype":"textquery",
                "language":"en"
                }
            params_encoded=urlencode(params)
            places_endpoint=f"{url}?{params_encoded}"
            r=requests.get(places_endpoint) 
            streetname=r.json()["result"]['formatted_address']
            address_list.append(streetname)
            supplier_list.append(name)
            try:
                phoneNumber=r.json()["result"]['international_phone_number']
                phone_list.append(phoneNumber)
            except:
                phoneNumberNA="N.A"
                phone_list.append(phoneNumberNA)   
            

            
DataFrame=pd.DataFrame({"Suppliername":supplier_list,"address":address_list,"PhoneNumber":phone_list})
indexDrop=DataFrame[DataFrame["address"]=="No address found"].index
DataFrame=DataFrame.drop(indexDrop)

address=DataFrame["address"].str.split(",", expand=True)
expansion1=address[0].str.split("(.*?)\s*(\d+(?:[/-]\d+)?)?$",expand=True)
ZipCity=address[1].str.split(" ", expand=True)
DataFrame["City"] = ZipCity[2]
DataFrame["Street"]=expansion1[1]
DataFrame["Streetnumber"]=expansion1[2]
DataFrame["Zip"] = ZipCity[1]
DataFrame["Country"]=address[2]      
merged_frame=pd.merge(vendor_data_pl,DataFrame,on="Supplier name")
zipaddress=zip(merged_frame["Street_x"].values,merged_frame["Street_y"].values)
similarity=[]
for x,y in zipaddress:
    similarity.append(fuzz.ratio(x,y))

merged_frame["Similarity"]=similarity
merged_frame=merged_frame[["Supplier name","Street_x","Street_y","Similarity","Streetnumber","City postal code","Zip","Country","PhoneNumber"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy neat solution:

```py
df.sort_values('Similarity', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Supplier Name')
```

If you had thousands of rows it wouldn't be too efficient since it requires sorting but it's still not too bad and rather neat.

The efficient way to do this is still quite neat so use whichever you like best:

```py
df.loc[df.groupby('Supplier Name')['Similarity'].idxmax()]
```

It still involves sorting but only within groups so at scale it would be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. Really helped me